# Setting __index for Torch Classes

Tags: lua, torch

Is it possible to set an __index method for torch classes? I have tried to implement a simple `dataset` class as outlined in the Deep Learning with Torch tutoral: ([ipynb here](https://github.com/soumith/cvpr2015/blob/master/Deep%20Learning%20with%20Torch.ipynb))

```lua
trainset = {
    inputs = {0, 1, 1, 0},
    targets = {1, 1, 1, 0}
}

index = function(t, i)
    return {t.inputs[i], t.targets[i]}
end

setmetatable(trainset, {
    __index = index
)
```

Which allows you to do `trainset[1]]` which returns `{0, 1}`.

However, implementing this as torch class does not work.

```lua
local torch = require("torch")

do 
    Dataset = torch.class("Dataset")

    function Dataset:__init(i, t)
        self.inputs = i
        self.targets = t
    end

    function Dataset.__index(t, v)
        print("inside index")
        return {
            rawget(t, inputs)[v],
            rawget(t, targets)[v]
        }
    end
end

Dataset({0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0}) -- fails
```

It seems that, upon object creation, `__index()` is called and fails since `index` and `targets` are not yet created. If `rawget` is not used, then it causes a stack overflow.

My understanding of Lua is limited, but I'm surprised to see `__index()` being called during object creation: I think there's stuff going on behind the scenes I don't fully understand.

Comment: It makes sense to emulate only numerical keys using `__index` metamethod.  I guess this will solve the problem: `if type(v) == 'number' then return {t.inputs[v], t.targets[v]} end`

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. It's not quite the whole story though, there are some torch-specific concerns (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torch classes all implement `__index`, which will look for `__index__` in the metatable, which is for overloading.

From the [docs](https://github.com/torch/torch7/tree/master/lib/luaT#operator-overloading):

> If one wants to provide **index** or **newindex** in the metaclass,
>   these operators must follow a particular scheme:
>
> **index** must either return a value and true or return false only. In the first case, it means **index** was able to handle the given
>   argument (for e.g., the type was correct). The second case means it
>   was not able to do anything, so __index in the root metatable can then
>   try to see if the metaclass contains the required value.

Which means for the example, the `__index__` (not `__index` !) method must check if `type(v) == "number"` and if not, return `false` so that `__index` can look for the value in the object metatable.

```lua
local torch = require("torch")

do 
    Dataset = torch.class("Dataset")

    function Dataset:__init(i, t)
        self.inputs = i
        self.targets = t
    end

function Dataset.__index__(t, v)
    if type(v) == "number" then
        local tbl =  {
            t.inputs[v],
            t.targets[v]
        }
        return tbl, true
    else
        return false
    end
end

local dset = Dataset({0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0})
dset[1] --> {0, 1}
```